# Trying to convert if else statement into ternary in javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-operator

```
if (props.name == "Computer"){
        if (result == "Won"){
            result = "Lost";
        }
        else if (result == "Lost"){
            result = "Won";
        }
    }
```

Tried converting to ternary, but failed to do so. (Have no idea how to mix up the first and second line).
Also, not sure about "HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT" this spot.

```
result =="Won" ? result="Lost": result=="Lost" ? result="Won" : <HAVE NO IDEA WHAT TO PUT>;
```

Comment: Why you need ternery operator. Code is more readable in  `if-else` block

Comment: just trying to practice ternary operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several different cases in your logic. Perhaps it's unclear to you. But this is what your attempts with the ternary operator have revealed:

- `props.name` could be something other than "Computer". What should be printed then?
- `result` could be something other than just `"Won"` or `"Lost"`

Anyway, let's build this ternary operator up:

```
result = props.name == "Computer" ? <YOUR CURRENT LOGIC> : <WHATEVER HAPPENS WHEN PROPS IS NOT COMPUTER>;
```

I am simply going to have the code return "result" as-is whenever we hit a case that was not defined by your if-else:

```
result = (props.name == "Computer" ? (result == "Won" ? "Lost" : "Won" ) : result);
```

Comment: oh yea, I wanted to leave it as result if it doesn't meet the condition. it worked! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
result = (props.name == "Computer" ? (result == "Won" ? "Lost" : "Won") : "What you want when props.name is not Computer");
```